# redshift query optimization: which is the better way multiple where conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to know which is more optimized

the below uses two where conditions

```
SELECT *
FROM
    "history"
WHERE 
    1=1 and history.createdOn >= (GETDATE() - INTERVAL '1 DAY')  and history.number = '2343434'
ORDER BY 
    id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

the below uses subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *and
   FROM "history"
   WHERE 
       1=1 and history.createdOn >= (GETDATE() - INTERVAL '1 DAY') 
   ORDER BY 
   id DESC
   ) as test
WHERE test.number = '2343434'
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: You can request a [Query plan - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html) for both of them and then compare the results (eg `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...`). I'd imagine that removing rows via WHERE _before_ doing the sort would be more efficient.